# Box2d Hide b2Body Wireframe

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

Hey,
Im using cocos2d and box2d and I want to turn off the wireframe around all bodies in my b2world.
How can I do this?

Thanks,
Oliver

Comment: you want to disable debug draw ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using GLESDebugDraw. Just don't use it. I suppose you have something like this in your physics layer init method

```
    debugDraw_ = new GLESDebugDraw(PTM_RATIO);      
    world_->SetDebugDraw(debugDraw_);

    uint32 flags = 0;
    flags += b2DebugDraw::e_shapeBit;
    flags += b2DebugDraw::e_jointBit;
    //      flags += b2DebugDraw::e_aabbBit;
    //      flags += b2DebugDraw::e_pairBit;
    //      flags += b2DebugDraw::e_centerOfMassBit;
    debugDraw_->SetFlags(flags);
```

Just delete (or comment) these strokes.